# How do I allow users to see other users' views based on taxonomy fields

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a bunch of nodes called 'article' with a taxonomy field attached called 'publication'

I have also added the 'publication' field to the user so he/she can choose which publications they want to see - they select these and then there's a view where they can only see their own selection, based on a contextual filter.

Question is, how can I let users select the option to see other users' chosen publication view. Can this be added to their setting page, along with the actual publications - /user/1/edit?destination=admin/people

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with views relationship and contextual filters. You can add a relationship that references users and publications and then add user id to filter the publication based on the result

Comment: That really doesn't help me at all I'm afraid. What view do I start with, a user view, term view? Thanks.

Comment: Create a publication view and add reference entity relationship User referencing Content from field_publication. new add user id in contextual filter. this will show all the publication a user has linked to.

Comment: I have already created this view, I want to enable a different user to see a view that another user has created.

Comment: So basically you'd like to have users and their publication, right?